# Will stainless steel heat up faster than a cordierite-based surface in a gas oven?

Tags: thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, metals, food

Background:

> As some may know, pizza stones, used to accumulate heat before the
> pizza dough is put into the oven, are often made of cordierite. If
> it's well heated it should provide the underside of the pizza with a
> slightly-scorched crust by the time the 90 seconds or so for crusting
> the upperside are over.
>
> I plan to special-order a round stainless steel (316) plate for my
> butane-burning gas oven, which reaches about 500 degrees Celsius. I
> want to estimate how well will the stainless steel heat up and then
> transfer heat in comparison to the cordierite stone, to adjust heat-up
> time and material thickness to prevent burning or under-cooking.

Question:

From one website I gathered the specific heat for stainless steel 316 is 490 J/kg.K while thermal conductivity is 13 W/m.K. For cordierite it's up to 850 and 1.7 respectively. So the heat capacity for the stainless steel is about 40% lower, but it's thermal conductivity is about 700% higher.

Should heat transfer from the gas burners within the oven be mostly conduction or radiation? How does that affect the ability of the stainless steel plate to heat up, and does its polishing level matter? And should the heat emitted back from the stainless steel have greater difficulty reaching the dough evenly considering the dough might not sit completely flat on the plate due to air pockets?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you place the pizza on the plate (steel or cordierite), then enter plate with pizza in the oven for cooking of the pizza?

Comment: @Gert The plan is to heat the steel plate in advance. Otherwise the underside of the pizza will probably remain a half-baked mess stuck to the plate by the time the cheese starts burning.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll formulate an answer.

Comment: @Gert Thanks. By the way, to add some more information, the pizza stone in this case would stay in the oven and the steel plate would sit on top of it. I saw in some place that people discussing this suggested a steel would cool down too quickly, and I planned to have the steel at just 2.5mm thickness so it won't weigh too much (the idea is to be able to rotate the plate itself relatively easily). Cordierite stones are usually over 1cm thick, which density-adjusted weigh like a 2.5mm stainless steel 316 or more. So perhaps that's a little under-massive, but with the reserved stone still below?

Answer (score 1):

We need to distinguish two processes here:

1. preheating of the plates, prior to use for 'cooking' the pizza,
2. use of the plates for 'cooking' pizza.

---

For the first process we assume the plate to be thin ($z$-direction) compared to its other dimensions and these other dimensions ($x$ and $y$-directions) to be small compared to the oven itself.

[image: Pizza plates]

If so then we can assume there are no temperature gradients in the plate:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}=0$$

In plain English this means that although the temperature $T(t)$ of the plate will rise during heating, the plate's temperature will be *homogeneous*.

At $500^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ oven temperature we can't exclude radiative heating, in addition to convective heating. But with the above assumption conductive heat transfer will not be considered.

Radiative heat transfer (oven$\to$plate) is prescribed by [Stefan Boltzmann Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) and looks like this, where $T_{\infty}$ is the oven temperature (presumed homogeneous and constant):

$$P_R=\sigma \left(T_{\infty}^4-T(t)^4\right)$$

Convective heat transfer is prescribed by [Newton's Law of Cooling/Heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Mathematical_formulation_of_Newton%27s_law)
$$P_C=hA\left(T_{\infty}-T(t)\right)$$
So:
$$P=P_R+P_C=\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
And:
$$\mathrm{d}q=m c_p\mathrm{d}T$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}T(t)}{\sigma \left(T_{\infty}^4-T(t)^4\right)+hA\left(T_{\infty}-T(t)\right)}=\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{mc_p}\tag{1}$$
The ODE $(1)$ could be integrated between $[0,T_0]$ and $[t,T(t)]$ (the *form of* the undetermined integral [can be found here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%20y%27%28x%29%20%2F%28b%28c-x%5E4%29%2Bd%28e-x%29%29%3D1)) but we don't really need to do this for our purpose.

Rather we can evalutate the RHS of $(1)$ which shows us that the temperature evolution $T(t)$ (or heating rate $\frac{\mathrm{d}T(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}$) will be slower for higher $c_p$, as well as for higher $m$. This is hardly surprising and well in line with intuitive expectations.

---

The 'cooking' phase can itself be regarded as the result of two processes:

1. radiative heating for the pizza top, as above,
2. heating of the pizza base by heat transfer from the plate to the pizza.

This second mode does pose some problems to a modeler and requires some choices to be made.

I suggest the lumped capacitance method [suggested in this excellent ebook](https://ahtt.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/AHTTv500.pdf) at p.194 to 196 (note that $\bar{h}$ in the text is not equal to $h$ above).

In it, the temperature of the pizza's base, is assumed to jump sharply at $t=0$ (the point we put the pizza on the plate) to some value $T_i$.

Comment: Thanks, although I perhaps I need it more dumbed-down in order to conclude anything for the oven situation, as I'm not sure how to apply your answer yet. Also worth noting is that A. there is a great thermal gradient in the oven as the burners are only at its innermost side, and B. regarding convective heating, I understand the gasses transfer heat throughout the air like that, but the metal itself is solid and thus isn't directly heated through convection but through conduction, and the question is how are radiative absorption and conductive absorption compare for stainless steel.

Comment: Ovens like the one you describe have remarkably homogeneous temperatures, due to hot gas turbulence. A steel plate in an oven like that receives heat from radiation, as well as **convection**. For a relatively thin plate heat **conduction** can be reasonably neglected (as I did). To evaluate the relative importance of *radiative* and *convective* heating, compare $P_R$ and $P_C$.

Comment: Also, please don't underestimate the power of simple experimentation: a kitchen IR thermometer and a stopwatch can go a very long way in understanding what is going on.

Comment: In regards to temperature homogeneousy, the inside is definitely hotter than the outside: I don't remember if I tested that myself after giving the cordierite a decent pre-heating time, but in reviews of a similarly-designed oven, which has the same open, no-door design (even if the opening is relatively narrow and designed to circulate turbulence inwards), it was shown the outermost part of the stone was maybe 300° Celsius vs 500° near the burners. I want to add a stainless steel plate so I could easily rotate the entire thing with the pizza, which is crucial for baking uniformity.

Comment: Of course the loven is hotter inside than out: it couldn't be any other way. Careful with 'reviews' written by laymen: much nonsense lies therein. *I want to add a stainless steel plate so I could easily rotate the entire thing with the pizza, which is crucial for baking uniformity.* What do you understand by that?

Comment: *it was shown the outermost part of the stone was maybe 300° Celsius vs 500° near the burners* Given enough time the temeoratures of the plate and oven equalise: that's Thermodynamics 101. A noted difference may be due to not enough time or poor measuring protocol.

Comment: I understand that I mean to rotate the pizza more easily than I can without a rotating plate. Regarding heat uniformity, because the front is open, it probably loses heat before the front end of the stone manages to reach the maximum temperature. I did measure about 500 degrees Celsius near the burners and even less than 300 when I first tested the oven. I don't remember if I run it for very long before that but I suppose it indeed won't reach close to 500 on that area. You can see how the oven is designed more or less by looking at photos of the Ooni Koda 12.

Comment: Nice oven! If the temperature really is non-uniform we have a *temperature field*: $T=u(x,y,z)$ which makes modelling very difficult. Only a numerical model could be developed, assuming $u(x,y,z)$ is known. I suggest taking a lot of temperatures at varying times $t$, to provide insight re. the questions you have.

Comment: That is the more expensive "original" the one I bought imitates, but they seem quite similar. I could measure better during the next batch of pizzas – but no plans currently as every time I'm burning the pizza due to insufficient maneuverability I get more and more agitated with the process. I'm still looking at shops able to create a plate the size I need, so hopefully it wouldn't be too expensive and would prove usable rather than another waste.

Comment: Can the oven temperature be set (chosen) in some way?

Comment: There is a valve that diminishes the burners to a point, and I do lower it to its minimum when the pizza is in the oven, but it's still quite difficult not to burn it as it needs just a slight mistaken push forward when you're trying to rotate the pizza with a peel to get burned or catch fire even, and also you need to start rotating after 20 to 30 seconds but usually the underside of the colder side isn't firm enough yet, which makes moving the pizza more problematic. So the options are either making tiny pizzas or making something that's easily rotatable.

Comment: I see. This whole proces is basically non-modelable. We can only model *subprocesses* here ((as I tried to do). Note that 'turning down the gas' will have little effect, as the desired temperature reduction will be far from instantaneous. 500 C BTW seems excessive to me to cook food in! Like I said: try do a lot of measurements to make some sense of things. Over and out.

Comment: These temperatures are mainly for neapolitan style pizza, which is traditionally baked in a wood fired brick oven. Lowering the burner fire is for trying to counteract the issue of turning the pizza quickly in accurately enough before/without causing it to catch fire. An easily rotatable surface is the best solution I can think of, which is why I wanted to understand how well a thin stainless steel plate should work. I suppose I will find out after buying something. Thanks!

Comment: Read and noted. Good luck!